# SSMS Designer Removing Square Brackets

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am designing a view that accesses tables in a linked server.

Every time I paste this query into the SQL pane, Intellisense removes the square brackets, and then complains that there's more than 3 prefixes.  I've tried turning Intellisense off, but it keeps happening:

```
SELECT   Loc.Address1, Loc.Address2, Loc.Address3, BP.BusinessPartnerName
FROM     [REPORTING.SOMESERVER.CA].Toast.dbo.BusinessPartnerLocations AS Loc LEFT OUTER JOIN
         [REPORTING.SOMESERVER.CA].Toast.dbo.BusinessPartner AS BP ON Loc.BusinessPartnerID = BP.BusinessPartnerID
```

to this:

```
SELECT   Loc.Address1, Loc.Address2, Loc.Address3, BP.BusinessPartnerName
FROM     REPORTING.SOMESERVER.CA.Toast.dbo.BusinessPartnerLocations AS Loc LEFT OUTER JOIN
         REPORTING.SOMESERVER.CA.Toast.dbo.BusinessPartner AS BP ON Loc.BusinessPartnerID = BP.BusinessPartnerID
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Why are you using the Query Designer? If you paste your query into a standard query window, SSMS won't rewrite it.

Comment: As a workaround, I find that it I just throw an extra period at the end of your query, the Query Designer fails to parse it, and gives me the opportunity to click Ignore. That seems to prevent any optimization, and then I can just remove the extra period once it ends up in the normal query window.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I'm designing a new view.  I'm a Mongo guy these days, so wrapping my head around SQL again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that encapsulating the server name in quotes made Intellisense ignore it.

```
FROM        ["REPORTING.SOMESERVER.CA"].Toast.dbo.BusinessPartnerLocations AS Loc LEFT OUTER JOIN
```